# SQL ignore parenthesis in name field for ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I would like rows returned in a MySQL query to be sorted alphabetically by surname for which I have an SQL query like:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  substring_index(name, ' ', -1) as surname
FROM
  my_table
ORDER BY 
  surname asc
```

However, *some* names have parenthesis to denote some special circumstance such as: `Laura Angel (retired)`

How can I modify my SQL above to ignore the parenthesised text, to sort by surname alphabetically?

Comment: what flavor of sql are you using? mysql, sql server, oracle etc... please put it and tag it

Comment: Great comment, it's MySQL and I have put it now

Answer (score 1):

Try with nested replaces to remove the parentheses.

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  substring_index(name, ' ', -1) as surname
ORDER BY 
REPLACE( REPLACE( surname  , '(' , '') , ')' , '') ASC;
```

Test and modify according to you version of SQL.
Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT id, 
  substring_index(rtrim(substring_index(name, '(', 1)), ' ', -1) as surname 
FROM test.test
ORDER BY 
  surname asc;
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will work for cases where names don't have a parenthesis.

Comment: It works :), the idea is to remove everything inside the parentheses if it exists.